# Logic apps union analytics query

Tags: azure, union, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

In azure stream analytics queries I can normally union results from different application insights scopes.

For example:

```
app("myapplicationinsights.europewest").customEvents 
| union app("myapplicationinsights.europenorth").customEvents
```

I would like to use the results from two different scopes in a logic app. But when I try this, I get the following output with status code 400:

```
{
  "Message": "User input is invalid. Please check query syntax, Chart Type or other parameters data. Response Status=HttpJsonResponse: ResultStatus=BadRequest, Response Content={\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"message\": \"The request had some invalid properties\",\r\n    \"code\": \"BadArgumentError\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"InsufficientAccessToResource\",\r\n        \"message\": \"Cannot access 'applicationinsights.europenorth' with the current credentials\",\r\n        \"target\": \"query\",\r\n        \"value\": \"applicationinsights.europenorth\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}\r\nclientRequestId: 02d4ffeb-906b-4230-b5df-fe5d482f9718"
}
```

The error is clear. But how can I specify more than one AIConnection in a logic app analytics query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Run query and list results (Preview)" was able to handle the union. So I have replaced my "Run Analytics query" by the "Run query and list results (Preview).